# Change Icon on header of react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, header, navigation, icons

I have a headerRight that is a star icon, and when the user clicks, it should become another star icon (filled).
Any direction to make this re-rendering on the navigation?
Any help would be appreciate. 
I am using redux to manage the states.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use state

```
state = {
  isClick : false,
}
```

and do conditional render

```
{
  isClick ? <IconFilled/> : <Icon>
}
```

and handle state using setState in your icon action "onPress"

Answer (score 0):

If it's a fleeting state change, and exclusive to your Nav component, then you should store the state of the user click in this.state, as mentioned by @KimHau.

But you're storing the result of the user click in the Redux store, which means it probably is meant to persist across your app.

Slightly modified:

```
render() {

    return (

       // ... your other jsx code
       { this.props.hasUserClicked ? < IconFilled /> : < Icon /> }

    )

}
```

Though it might be more convenient to modify the *< Icon />* component to accept a prop, so it can manage its own state.

```
  < Icon userClicked={ this.props.hasUserClicked }/>
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.
I have created a component for the icon and handling the click inside this component as I dont Have access to the Icon from material-icons-vector-icons.

Thank you guys, you really helped me.